# wp-content/uploads/year/month returns 404

Tags: uploads, htaccess, media

I have a litespeed hosting

I have disabled all plugins and all wordpress related htaccess rewrites.

If I go to https://digitalzoomstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/2023/ - then I can see the directory listing

[image]

but if I enter any directory, I get 404
[image]

I think I can correlated, that when this happened, I changed the permission system to the wp-content/uploads directory as a suggestion from **Really Simple SSL** Plugin

I used **0744** for the directories and **0644** for the files

Any ideas ? I have tried anything I can think of

Comment: You'll need to check with your hosting provider's support team about this.

Answer (score 1):

solved it

actually the directories need **0755**